# How to run gui app as another user on wayland

Tags: users, wayland

With Xorg, I could just do

```
xhost +si:localuser:foxy
```

to run GUI app as foxy user.

But can I do this on Wayland ? I tried following:-

```
chmod o+rw /run/user/1000/wayland-0
```

but It still gives Permission denied

```
[foxy@titan levi]$ QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000  konsole
Failed to create wl_display (Permission denied)
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm using kwin_wayland 5.20.2

EDIT: I dont want to use root

Comment: [Duplicates?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710046/how-to-run-a-graphical-application-as-another-user)

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck nah, I Dont want to use xwayland.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to user sudo su username or sudo su - username and then type the name of the app. This is the trivial way.

Comment: yeah, this works but I want to run app as less privileged user

Comment: You can see this link: https://serverfault.com/questions/507807/the-opposite-of-su-run-a-command-without-root-privileges I hope this partially suites your needs.

Comment: `$ sudo su username` then `xcalc` or `logseq` or whatever, and nothing works...