# How to run a graphical application as another user?

Tags: xorg, wayland, gtk, qt, multiuser

Let's an user A (`userA`) wants to run in his graphical session a graphical application as user B (`userB`). How is it done it on a modern GNU/Linux system?

Comment: X11 or Wayland? Both?

Comment: I'd like the same method to work on both seamlessly. In the worst case I want to run the application with Xwayland on the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Short answer

Install the
[`run-as`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/run-as)
scripts and run:

```
run-as -X <user> <command>
```

##### Long answer

Write and run a script to authorize `userB` to access `userA` graphical session.

```bash
/home/userA/.local/bin/xhost_userB
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
xhost +si:localuser:userB
```

**Optional**: allow access at login.

```
/home/userA/.config/autostart/xhost_userB.desktop
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Graphical auth for user B
Comment=Authorize user B to run graphical software in this session
GenericName=userB xauth
Exec=/home/userA/.local/bin/xhost_userB
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Some applications may require extra services.

```bash
/home/userA/.local/bin/xhost_userB_extra_services
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
systemctl --user restart dbus
systemctl --user import-environment
```

Create a script to run the application as userB (es. Seahorse).

```bash
/home/userA/.local/bin/application
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
machinectl shell --uid=userB \
                 --setenv=DISPLAY="${DISPLAY}" \
                 --setenv=NO_AT_BRIDGE=1 \
                 .host \
                 /home/userA/.local/bin/xhost_userB_extra_services

machinectl shell --uid=userB \
                 --setenv=DISPLAY="${DISPLAY}" \
                 --setenv=NO_AT_BRIDGE=1 \
                 .host /usr/bin/application
```

Note: it works on Wayland too if XWayland is running.